# Text Editor in Angular js

Tags: html, css

Have used the below code for text editor with bullet listing in it.

```
<div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="comments" 
    style="border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;" 
    ta-toolbar="[['ul']]" name="htmlcontent1" class="form-control myform1-height" 
    ta-html-editor-class="form-control myform1-height">
</div>
```

the issue is the text editor doesn't popup keyboard when touched.
have used below css for it.

```
.closing-textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #dee5e7;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.closing-comments-wrapper .form-control {

    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    /*border: 2px dashed #DDD;*/
}

.closing-comments-wrapper .ta-editor.form-control.myform1-height, .ta-scroll-window.form-control.myform1-height  {

    min-height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.closing-comments-wrapper .form-control.myform1-height > .ta-bind {

    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}

.closing-comments-wrapper .btn-group>.btn:first-child {

    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: right;
}

.closing-comments-wrapper .btn-group {

    float: right;
}

.ta-hidden-input {

  display: none;

}
```

Comment: Show the demo of this code

Comment: @kalpeshpatel referred this link https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular

Comment: are you looking for some thing like stack overflow textbox??

Comment: @Aravind textArea with a option for using bullets

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas can you add a plunker or fiddle for the same?